# What is moduleclass_sfx about?

Tags: php, joomla

I saw this $params->get('moduleclass_sfx') in one of the custom modules and found it is also part of the core code as well. Wondering what this is about? Could not find any links to any Joomla documentation on the google search hence not sure what exactly this is about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A module class suffix is a paramater used to add a custom class to a module.

For example, let's say you have a template with a left sidebar and in that sidebar you have two different modules. The default background colour for modules in the sidebar is grey. However, you want the first module background colour to be red. This is when module class suffixes come in handy.

Default modules would be like so:

**html:**

```
<div class="module">
```

**css:**

```
.module { background: grey; }
```

If you insert a module class suffix such as "**test**", it would result in the following:

```
<div class="module test">
```

The css for this would then look like the following:

```
.module.test { background: red; }
```

Template providers use module class suffixes to provide more of a variety of styling for modules. Take a look at [this template](http://www.yootheme.com/demo/joomla/moreno), on the top menu, go to "*Features*", then "*Layouts*" to get a good example.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been using Joomla! in a while, but as far as I remember `moduleclass_sfx` in itself is nothing special, it's just one of the parameter of a module you can modify in your admin panel.

Usually it was a CSS classname you could add to a module (for the frontend view) in order to personalize it further.

So that expression , `$params->get('moduleclass_sfx')` simply takes (usually in a Controller) the "moduleclass_sfx" index (i.e. the name of the admin panel input for that module in which you insert the CSS class) out of all the module parameters (`$params`).

I guess the high occurence is because it's a standard way to name that input field (it's a useful and common feature after all, which allows a greater deal of customization), that's why you find it both in custom modules and core ones, but I don't think is something vital: I mean, in your custom module you could name it 'css_suffix', call it with `$params->get('css_suffix')` and achieve the same result.